# Asignar valor de DF en cadena texto en Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Como puedo asignar el valor de un dataframe a una cadena texto, ya al momento de concatenar la variable, no reconoce el valor, sino el nombre.

**Ejemplo:**

- He creado unas variables para traerme el día, mes y año actual

now     = datetime.now()
dfDia   = "{:02d}".format(now.day) # Me trae el día actual (13)

dfMes   = "{:02d}".format(now.month) # Me trae el día actual (06)

- En otra recuadro tengo mi cadena conexión

G_PathFinal     =   'Processed/BRONZE/SLIM/FACT_LABORATORIO/2023/' + dfMes + '/' dfDia + '/FACT_LABORATORIO.avro'

Cuando ejecuto me sale error, por que no reconoce la ruta del archivo y claro es porque no captura  los valores, sino el nombre del df

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor podrían ayudarme.
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques imágenes de código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21) o errores. Publica el texto del código y el texto de los errores como tal. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por la foto que mostrás dond dice "SyntaxError" y leyendo esa línea diría que te falta un **+** entre de **'/'** y **dfDia**:  `...+dfMes + '/' + dfDia + '/FACT...` ()

Saludos